# Implementing a recursion algorithm on a 3D array in c

Tags: c, recursion

I need to implement a function with the following signature:

```
int rec(int board[SIZE][SIZE][10])
```

* SIZE is a const.

The function should be recursive.
The board itself is 2 dimensional, and the 3rd dimension is used for holding the cell's possible values.

My question is: how can i scan the board recursivly, without the function accepting the current row and column of the board as parameters?

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: I thought about global variables, but I realized that it's problemtic because i'll advance through the board in several directions, and keeping track of those variables will be tricky

Comment: Either your homework assignment is bogus, or you're paraphrasing it incorrectly (the latter is more likely). Depending on what you're planning to do with the board, you may not actually need to pass row and columns indices.

Comment: I need to scan all the cells in the board, and for each one if there is only 1 possible value left, assign that value to the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your function actually have to be recursive? You know there's only 3 dimensions to this array, so an algorithm that scans the entire array from start to finish can be implemented with nothing more than 3 nested for loops (2 to identify the current cell, and one to iterate over all 10 values in the cell).

On that note, when you say "holding the cell's possible values", does this cell actually have 10 separate ints that you need to track? If instead it's simply an int that has 10 possible distinct values, then that third dimension to the array is unnecessary. While there may be 10 possible values, the cell can only hold one of them at a time.

Comment: The function has to be recursive (it's a homework assignment). And again I know that this implementation isn't perfect (regarding the 3rd dimension of the array), but it's imposed on me.